# Fragment transition jank caused by slow measure/layout pass

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, animation

My app has a list of items, and clicking on one brings in a fragment with details on the item. The details contain a somewhat complicated RecyclerView (many small views with a FlexBoxLayoutManager), and the measure/layout pass can go over 50ms.

That delay causes the app to drop a few frames at the start of the fragment transition, causing a fairly noticable "jump".

I see a few possible ways to avoid this:

1. Don't populate the RecyclerView (or make it a stub) until the transition is finished. Downside: user sees a half-empty fragment animating in.
2. Delay the whole transition until the new fragment has been measured and laid out. Downside: user feedback is delayed.
3. Start the list's exit animation, but delay the enter animation until the new fragment has been measured and laid out. This is what I would like to do.

Unfortunately, the exit animation would have to run on the main thread, and the same goes for measure/layout; there's nothing like `AsyncLayoutInflater` for measure/layout, right?

So, then, is there really no way to implement #3? If that's the case, does anyone have a better solution?

### Demo app

This app simply adds a sleep in the `onMeasure()` method whenever the "slow measure" checkbox is checked.

Here's a [screen recording](https://gfycat.com/CarefulShyBantamrooster) -- note the difference when the checkbox is toggled, how it jumps (most noticable on the left with the text and on the right edge between the old/new fragment).

#### MainActivity.kt

```
var beSlow = false

class SlowWidget @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : TextView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        if (beSlow) {
            SystemClock.sleep(100)
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    }
}

class SlowFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup?, state: Bundle?): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, parent, false)
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var i = 0
    val colors = arrayOf(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.CYAN)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main)
    }

    fun viewClicked(v: View): Unit {
        beSlow = slowbox.isChecked
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out)
                .replace(R.id.container, SlowFragment().apply {
                    arguments = Bundle().apply {
                        putInt("color", colors[i++ % colors.size])
                    }
                })
                .commit()
    }
}
```

#### res/layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:text="Switch"
        android:onClick="viewClicked"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/slowbox"
        android:text="slow measure"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

#### res/layout/fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<se.dolkow.debug.animdemo.SlowWidget
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rainbow"
    />
```

#### res/drawable/rainbow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#ffff0000"
        android:centerColor="#ff00ff00"
        android:endColor="#ff8000ff"
        />
</shape>
```

#### res/anim/slide_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:shareInterpolator="false"
    >
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
</set>
```

#### res/anim/slide_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
</set>
```

Comment: Not what I'm asking. I've already rewritten it twice; first as a custom ViewGroup, and then as a single custom View. It's fast enough now, but my question still stands: is it possible to get smooth animations when adding a slow-to-measure/layout fragment?

Comment: Since the previous commenter seems to have deleted their comment: they wanted to see my layouts and improve on them.